# Tweepy: Rotate API object in the middle of Cursor iteration

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So basically I'm trying to obtain the followers of a user with many of them. I'm using tweepy for this and I can't simply wait the 60 seconds every time I hit the limit or this will take too long. So this is my approach, to me it makes sense as it s keeping track of next_cursor (which is initialized as -1):

```
while getting_followers:
    try:
        follower_cursors = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=userid, next_cursor=current_cursor)
        for follower_cursor in follower_cursors.pages():
            temp_list = temp_list + follower_cursor
            print "Getting Followers..."

        getting_followers = False

    except Exception as e:
        print "Error obtaining node followers"
        print e
        if str(e) == "Not authorized.":
            print "Not authorized, skipping.", str(userid)
            getting_followers = False
        elif str(e) == "[{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.', 'code': 34}]":
            print e
            getting_followers = False
        else:
            print "Changing accounts."
            api = rotateAccounts()
            current_cursor = follower_cursors.iterator.next_cursor
```

the problem is this doesn't work, the Cursor restarts every time I rotate api, it doesn't remember the current cursor

Comment: But what's your question or error?

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is this doesn't work, the Cursor restarts every time  rotate api, it doesn't remember the current cursor

Comment: Do you want the last line of your snippet to set the `current_cursor` to `follower_cursor`?

Comment: no, I'm getting next_cursor from inside the Cursor object, and then when I restart the loop and create a new Cursor object I want to set its next_cursor value to current_cursor, which should be the value the Cursor had right before hitting the limit

Comment: In that case, rather than just create a new cursor object each time you start the loop, why don't you check to see if there's already a cursor object when you start the loop. If there is, keep it as the current cursor, else create a new cursor